# "All rooms" versus "all the rooms"

Tags: definite-articles, all-the

When a hotel gives a description of the rooms in the facility, which sentence is correct and why?

> All the rooms are equipped with a free internet connection.
>
> All rooms are equipped with a free internet connection.

Comment: Related: [difference between 'all' and 'all the'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4863/difference-between-all-and-all-the).

Comment: @RegDwight: I read the related post before I asked this and it doesn't help resolve anything.

Comment: In that case, it would have been beneficial to include that information in the body of your question right away. Explaining *why* it doesn't help you would be appreciated, too. Lastly, you always have the option of putting a bounty on a question you deem unanswered or answered poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ordinary speech and writing, I would say "all the rooms".

In a promotional context "all rooms" is common.

Comment: +1 for what intuitively sounds right to me. Dropping the word "the" does indeed have overtones of "ad-speak".

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, because both are idiomatic shortenings of grammatically correct sentences. The elided words are clear from the context. The sentence

> All the rooms are equipped with a free internet connection.

is a concise expression of the more verbose sentence

> All [of] the rooms [in this hotel] are equipped with a free internet connection.

Likewise, the sentence

> All rooms are equipped with a free internet connection.

is a shortened version of the sentence

> [In this hotel,] all rooms are equipped with a free internet connection.

There are other possible "source" sentences, but to me, these seem to be the most likely candidates.

Comment: You seem to imply that OP's contructions are somehow "less grammatical" because they don't include "of" and/or "in this hotel", but I don't think this has any relevance to grammatical correctness.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm not sure what I said that would imply that. I explicitly said that both are correct!

Comment: Well, you also say they're both "idiomatic shortenings", which seems at best "questionable" to me. You might as well say "rooms" is an idiomatic shortening of "rooms available for hire", since there will be other rooms in the building that *don't* have an internet connection, such as the staff toilets.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't think there's anything questionable about it. Grammatically speaking, it's no different from what happens when one says, for example, "thank you." That's a full sentence; the subject, "I," is implicit, and inferred from context. Likewise, here the modifier "in this hotel" is left implicit, as is, perhaps, the modifier "available for hire." Or perhaps there's some context in which "rooms" could indeed refer to the staff toilets; it all depends. But none of that has any bearing on the grammaticality of the sentences in question.

Comment: As it happen, I think "Thank you" *is* an idiomatic shortening, since it stands for "I thank you". The possibility that there's also an implicit "...for what you have done" does not seem to me to be idiomatic. But my definition of "idiomatic" may differ from yours. In general I consider idiomatic usage to be that which deviates grammatically and/or semantically from standard usage (i.e. - doesn't follow standard grammar, or doesn't mean exactly what it seems to).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that must be the source of our disagreement. I'm thinking of "idiomatic" as meaning "[linguistic usage that is grammatical and natural to native speakers of a language](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idiom)." You'll have to scroll down a bit to find that one; so perhaps I am using "idiomatic" somewhat idiomatically (in your sense) :).

Comment: senderle, I think that what @FumbleFingers is unhappy with is your use of "shortening", and of "source" sentence: the implication is that there is a full form, and these are shortened versions of it, hence a hierarchy of "more full" (and by implication "more correct") sentences. This is not true - the shorter and longer forms have equal status grammatically. You may not have intended this hierarchy, but it is strongly suggested by your wording.