# Definite article usage and word ordering in 'all the equipment necessary to create a network'

Tags: word-order, definite-articles

I have a sentence where I am not sure about the word order, and if the definite article should be used or not.

Which version is correct:

1. *It is a system which includes all equipment necessary to create a network.*
2. *It is a system which includes all the equipment necessary to create a network.*
3. *It is a system which includes all necessary equipment to create a network.*
4. *It is a system which includes all the necessary equipment to create a network.*

Comment: I reckon all those variants are correct.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thanks, English is not my native language, and I got a suggestion to remove the definite article from the second sentence (which was the original one), so I basically wanted to check if an exact rule can be applied in this case.

Comment: [Difference between 'all' and 'all the'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4863/difference-between-all-and-all-the), [“All rooms” versus “all the rooms”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36379/all-rooms-versus-all-the-rooms)

Comment: What AndrewLeach said. But I would add that for me at least, including *"the"* suggests there may only be one such "set of equipment". Without it, there's more of an implication that other combinations of (potentially different) components could be used to create a network, but at least the reader can be assured that this particular system doesn't *require* any additional components. Also, I'd use the word *components* (which can comfortably apply to both hardware and software) rather than *equipment* (which often only and specifically applies to "hardware").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, yes, the intention was to emphasize that a measurement device comes bundled with everything necessary for it to work, no additional accessories needed. But as long as it's won't hurt anyone's ears, I don't think anyone will bother with these details. Thanks!

Comment: I think many people would be more likely to go for something like *"The **package** includes **everything you need** to create a network"* (perhaps partly because introducing *"you"* adds a reassuring level of immediacy and informality), but I doubt anyone would be bothered by any of your variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all correct, but I feel 4. is the most appropriate.If equipment is necessary, it will most probably be unique, hence the "the", I feel, should be there. And for some reason "necessary to create a network" sounds awkward... "required" sounds better if you want that ordering.

Comment: I can't really agree with that. I think all four variants are "acceptable", but I find #2 to be the most natural, and #4 the most stilted.